# Parsing datetime in AM/PM format

Tags: r

I am trying to parse Date-time in AM/PM format in R. I found that '%p' can handle this. However, when I try this:

```
mydate <- as.POSIXct("01.01.1970 01:00:00 PM", format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S %p", tz = "UTZ")
mydate
[1] "1970-01-01 01:00:00 UTZ"
> as.numeric(mydate)
[1] 3600
```

This is clearly 1 AM. I would have expected the output:

```
[1] "1970-01-01 13:00:00 UTZ"
[1] 46800
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is considering as 1 AM instead of 1 PM, hence you get 3600 as output.

```
as.POSIXct("01.01.1970 01:00:00 PM", format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S %p", tz = "UTC")
#[1] "1970-01-01 01:00:00 UTC"
```

The document at `?strptime` says

> %p
>   AM/PM indicator in the locale. Used in conjunction with %I and not with %H. An empty string in some locales (and the behaviour is undefined if used for input in such a locale).

You need to use `%I` instead of `%H`

```
mydate <- as.POSIXct("01.01.1970 01:00:00 PM", format="%d.%m.%Y %I:%M:%S %p", 
                     tz = "UTC")

as.numeric(mydate)
#[1] 46800
```

---

An alternative with `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
seconds(mdy_hms("01.01.1970 01:00:00 PM"))
#[1] "46800S"
```

Comment: I don't know what locale means. But it clearly solved my problem. Many thanks!